# Trouble using chain rule

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

> Write out the chain rule for $\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}$, where $h(u,v) = g(u(x,y,z), v(x,y,z))$.

I think it's $\frac{\partial g}{\partial u} \cdot \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial v} \cdot \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$.

> Use this to calculate the partial derivative with respect to $x$ of $\textbf{D} (g \circ f)$ at $(0, 1, 0)$ where $g(u,v) = (e^u, u + \sin v)$ and $f(x,y,z) = (xy, yz)$.

So first I calculate the partial derivative of $g$ w.r.t $u$ according to my previous answer (the first step is to obtain $\frac{\partial g}{\partial u} \cdot \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$), so:

$$\left( \begin{array}{cc}
e^u & 0 \\
1 & \cos v \\\end{array} \right)$$

However, this is the entire derivative. How do I write out the partial derivative of $g$ with respect to $u$ only without a matrix?

Comment: I can understand your finding the notation puzzling:  I've definitely seen better expressions of this sort of problem.  Since we are taking the derivative of $ \ g \ \circ \ f \ $ , I believe we are to read it that $ \ f(x,y,z) \ = \ (\ u(x,y,z) \ ,  \ v(x,y,z) \ ) \ = \ (xy \ , \ yz) \ $ .

Comment: Do you still need help with this?

Comment: No, but thank you